# Will Android application be still available on Google Play Store while I am transferring it to a different Google Play developer account?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to move an Android application from my current developer account to a new one. I wonder whether the application will be still be available for users to download on Google Play Store, while application is getting transferred to the other developer account. In other words, will there be any interruptions in terms of availability of the app on Google Play Store for users, until the whole transfer process is complete?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I wonder whether the application will be still be available for users
>   to download on Google Play Store

Yes, it will be available.

> While application is getting transferred to the other developer
>   account. In other words, will there be any interruptions in terms of
>   availability of the app on Google Play Store for users

No. There will be no interruption. Google will check your request. This will take 24 to 48 hours. If this request is accepted the App will be transfered  to the new developer account.

Comment: I've already been on this thread, but haven't found anything about the question I asked. Can you point me in the right direction?